Create new unique identifier numbers (ids)
Consider the following dataset and corresponding code:
mydata<-data.frame(id = c("R001", "R002", "R002", "R003", "R003", "R003"),
                   year = c(2014, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2017),
                   maledummy = c(1,0,0, 1,1,1))


#select non duplicates
mydata1<-mydata[!duplicated(mydata[c("id")]),]


#select duplicates
mydata2<-mydata[duplicated(mydata[c("id")]),]

#change id numbers of duplicate observation into name with two letters and two numbers
#??

#bind them together to the new dataset
mydatafinal<-rbind(mydata1, mydata2)

In the dataset above, I have a number of students (id) that belong to a graduation cohort (year). Some students only belong to one graduation cohort (R001), while others belong to two or even three graduation cohorts (R002 belongs to two cohorts and R003 belongs to three cohorts). This could for instance happen if people obtain more than one education degree (i.e. two bachelor’s, one master).
I would like to make the id number unique for those workers that graduate more than once. I know how to select the double ids (see the code). In the next step, I would like to replace the id number with another unique id that consists of four random letters or numbers (in the code above, I state two letters and two numbers, but it could be any combination). However, this newly created id should be unique. In other words, none of the other observations that get a new id should get the same name.

Can you show what would be an acceptable result for your sample data?

Using the dplyr package with the base R paste0() and sample() functions, you can achieve this. Note that I ran set.seed(1) to ensure this example results are reproducible, omit set.seed() for your actual use case.
I have added two options here:

return NA if the worker only graduated once
return original id if the worker only graduated once

library(dplyr)

mydata <- data.frame(id = c("R001", "R002", "R002", "R003", "R003", "R003"),
                     year = c(2014, 2014, 2015, 2014, 2015, 2017),
                     maledummy = c(1,0,0, 1,1,1))

# set.seed(1)

result <- mydata |>
  group_by(id) |>
  mutate(
    new_id = if_else(n() > 1, paste0(sample(c(LETTERS, 0:9), 4), collapse = ""), NA)
         ) |>
  ungroup()

result
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   id     year maledummy new_id
#   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 R001   2014         1 NA    
# 2 R002   2014         0 NR6U  
# 3 R002   2015         0 NR6U  
# 4 R003   2014         1 UJGI  
# 5 R003   2015         1 UJGI  
# 6 R003   2017         1 UJGI 

result <- mydata |>
  group_by(id) |>
  mutate(new_id = case_when(
    n() > 1 ~ paste0(sample(c(LETTERS, 0:9), 4), collapse = ""),
    TRUE ~ id
  )) |>
  ungroup()

result
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   id     year maledummy new_id
#   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 R001   2014         1 R001  
# 2 R002   2014         0 O6TF  
# 3 R002   2015         0 O6TF  
# 4 R003   2014         1 JT18  
# 5 R003   2015         1 JT18  
# 6 R003   2017         1 JT18 


Another approach with base R:

get all distinct alphanumeric 4-grams:

uids <- apply(combn(c(0:9, letters), 4), 2, \(xs) paste0(xs, collapse = ''))


sort your dataframe by id:

mydata <- mydata[order(mydata$id),]


assign a distinct ngram new_id to each original id, regardless of frequency:

mydata$new_id <- with(mydata,
                      rep(head(uids, length(unique(id))),
                          times = rle(id)$lengths
                      )
)


set final_id to id or new_id depending on uniqueness:

mydata$final_id <- 
  with(mydata,
       ifelse(id %in% names(Filter(\(x) x > 1, table(id))),
              new_id,
              id
       )
  )

result:
> mydata
##     id year maledummy new_id final_id
## 1 R001 2014         1   0123     R001
## 2 R002 2014         0   0124     0124
## 3 R002 2015         0   0124     0124
## 4 R003 2014         1   0125     0125
## 5 R003 2015         1   0125     0125
## 6 R003 2017         1   0125     0125


You can use the function below to generate unique combinations of alpha and/or numeric of length 4.
unique_random <- function(x, n.alpha, n.digit=4-n.alpha, all.unique=TRUE) {
  alphas <- digits <- NULL
  
  if(n.alpha + n.digit != 4) stop("n.alpha and n.digit must sum to 4")
  
    if(all.unique) 
      n <- length(x)
    else
      n <- length(unique(x))

  if(n.alpha>0) {
     ALPHAS <- do.call(paste0, expand.grid(lapply(1:n.alpha, \(x) LETTERS)))
     alphas <- sample(ALPHAS, n)
  }
  if(n.digit>0) {
     DIGITS <- formatC(1:10^n.digit - 1, width=n.digit, flag="0")
     digits <- sample(DIGITS, n)
  }
  
  if(all.unique)
    paste0(alphas, digits)
  else {
    reps <- rle(x)$lengths
    rep(paste0(alphas, digits), reps)
  }
}


unique_random(mydata2$id, n.alpha=2)
# [1] "XS24" "UR77" "PX75"

unique_random(mydata2$id, 4)
#[1] "JDLO" "CLOI" "VWMF"

unique_random(mydata2$id, 4, all.unique=FALSE)
#[1] "DFFZ" "ROXG" "ROXG"


You could do as follows:
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, id:=paste0(id, "-", rowid(id))]

Output:
       id  year maledummy
   <char> <num>     <num>
1: R001-1  2014         1
2: R002-1  2014         0
3: R002-2  2015         0
4: R003-1  2014         1
5: R003-2  2015         1
6: R003-3  2017         1

